# Connecting PEPPER with ROS

Tags: ros, naoqi, pepper

I am facing several problems using ROS and trying to connect it with PEPPER, I am using ros-noetic w/ python 2.7, I can’t import the naoqi module, neither the qi, I don’t really know what to do, I am stuck.
If you have any other solution, please let me know, even if I have to install a different ros distro.

Thank you all.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.